# Neo4j - Checking values validity in import-cypher statement

Tags: neo4j

I need to make sure that only not `null` values are passed to Neo4j through [import-cypher](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#cypher-import) from a CSV file.
I tried some Cypher formulations but neither has worked so far.

```
import-cypher -i in.csv -d ; case {name} when '' then null else {name} end as name, case {age} when '' then null else {age} end as age create (n {name: name, age: age})
```

It returns:

```
SyntaxException: Invalid input 'a': expected 'r/R' (line 1, column 2)
"case {name} when '' then null else {name} end as name, case {age} when '' then
null else {age} end as age create (n {name: name, age: age})"
  ^
```

Can someone help out please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better variant is to use the Cypher LOAD CSV, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-load-csv.html ?

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'm already using it in another use case. I just wanted to ask what could be the problem here? Do I understand that the query is correct?